# LibreOffice does not completely use Word's "standard" format for paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, templates

When opening existing Word documents with LibreOffice (current version: 5.0.5.2), most things look pretty well. But there is a problem: our Word's "standard" paragraph has single line spacing, and no space after paragraphs, while LibreOffice uses 115% line spacing and some space after paragraphs (other parameters seem to have been converted correctly).

I already created a document template based on a corrected version of a Word document, and set that template as standard. Freshly created LibreOffice documents show correct formatting. But any opened Word document still shows up wrongly.

How can that be solved?